# problems getting onpageshow and onpagehide listeners working

Tags: javascript, html

unable to get `pagehide` and `pageshow` working

```
<script>
    console.log( 'adding pagehide / pageshow' );
    window.addEventListener( 'pagehide', function() { console.log( 'page hide' ); } );
    window.addEventListener( 'pageshow', function() { console.log( 'page show' ); } );
</script>
```

getting console message

```
adding pagehide / pageshow
```

but when move to different tabs or between apps, `pagehide` and `pageshow` seem not to fire.

99% sure I'm being stupid, but cannot see what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving to different tabs or apps triggers the `blur` and `focus` listeners, not the `pagehide` or `pageshow` listeners. For example:

```
console.log( 'adding blur / focus' );
window.addEventListener( 'blur', function() { console.log( 'blur' ); } );
window.addEventListener( 'focus', function() { console.log( 'focus' ); } );
```

Should work.

Comment: thanks!  had really mis-applied pageshow.  according to mdn: The pageshow event is fired when a session history entry is being traversed to.